# Android Search with tabs

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

I'm trying to implement some kind of search to my app to filter data in a TabLayout and ViewPager with Fragments in it.

Part of MyFragment with ViewPager and TabLayout:

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        search = view.findViewById(R.id.search);
        pager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        TabLayout tabs = view.findViewById(R.id.tab);

        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        viewModel.data.observe(this, entities ->
        {
            if (entities != null) {
                repo.updateData(entities);
                pager.setAdapter(adapter);
                tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);
            }
        });

        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.length() >= 2) {
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                ContactsListFragment fragment = (ContactsListFragment) adapter.instantiateItem(pager, i);
                if (fragment.isAdded()) fragment.setSearch(s);
            }
}
                else {for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                MyListFragment fragment = (MyListFragment) adapter.instantiateItem(pager, i);
                if (fragment.isAdded()) fragment.setSearch("");
            }
}
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

When I try to pass String object to MyListFragment (only RecyclerView inside) and change data in adapter, it says that my RecyclerView is null.

How can I pass a String object to every fragment of ViewPager and filter data in them?

Comment: You're stating that the IDE tells you that a `RecyclerView` is null, yet there is no sign of a `RecyclerView` in your code above. It's impossible to help you out, if you don't rephrase your question and add the important bits of code missing. If you're getting a stacktrace, add that to the question as well.
The code, you've added so far: do you believe the issue is in this part of code at all?
And please clean up your code - it's very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to it. I tried to get a Fragment instance not correctly.

Old code part (Getting fragment from adapter):

```
MyListFragment fragment = (MyListFragment) adapter.instantiateItem(pager, i);
```

New code part (Getting fragment from FragmentManager):

```
MyListFragment fragment = (MyListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + pager.getCurrentItem());
```